# Create dynamics labels in a loop Vb.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, microsoft-dynamics, label

I am making a code that would create some labels automatically from a .txt file. I already have one but it doesn't work, it just creates only one label.

There is my code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form5

    Public uf8Encoding As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    Public lignes() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("clients.txt")
    Public lineCount As Integer = IO.File.ReadAllLines("clients.txt").Length ' lineCount = 7
    Public a As Integer = 1
    Public position As Integer = 10
    Public lb As Label()

    Private Sub Form5_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub loop1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ReDim lb(lineCount - 1)
        For i = 0 To lineCount - 1
            lb(i) = New Label
            lb(i).Name = "Label" & a
            lb(i).Text = lignes(i)
            lb(i).Location = New Point(position, 10)
            position += 10
            Me.Controls.Add(lb(i))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: No idea if this is your issue but all your labels have the same Name, "Label1" lb(i).Name = "Label" & a.  All of you labels are on the same horizontal line New Point(position, 10) and 10 pixels seems far to small a shift in position

Comment: Try setting  lb(i).AutoSize = true

Comment: Give them a with and a height.

Comment: Thanks tolanj, i think it's that beacause I forgot to put my increment of a in my code. I'll will check that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels are on top of each other, if you change the position increment to 100 you will be able to see the others.

You can clearly see the problem if you set the BackColor of the label.

If you set the AutoSize to true, they will use the bare minimum space and you will be able to see the next label even with 10 as distance.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this is your issue but all your labels have the same Name, "Label1" lb(i).Name = "Label" & a.

increment a in the loop  a += 1 . and all label have a different name.